# Should mods start making webapp-rec questions as CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, public-beta

Now that we have several mods, should we convert new questions that are marked as [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) to community wiki?

[This post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/is-community-wiki-the-synonym-for-poll/173#173) explains why they should be community wiki.

I would recommend that if we do start doing this that we post a comment which explains why it happened, possibly linking back to that post above.

Comment: Also see [this post](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-rec-tags-be-added).  Maybe it is just me but I'm not certain the community knows where it stands on that issue.

Comment: [webapp-rec](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/479/what-does-tag-mean-when-is-it-used/480#480)

Answer (score 6):

I'm rather new to this Q&A, but [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) is by far and large [the most common tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags) here.

On Gaming, list-of-X moderation has been very strict, which has brought tough discussion of what list questions would be acceptable. It also has not stopped game-rec questions from trickling in, however.

My stance on this is that if the question is specific enough that only a few, non commonly known web apps cover your specific needs, recommendation questions can be good: they need expert answers that generic lists of software on Wikipedia cannot give.

On the other hand, if the question is sufficiently broad, people will stop voting for the answers and start voting for the apps, turning the question into a [popularity contest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) that should not generate any rep, should it be allowed to pollute Google results at all. (Yes, I know that by linking to it I increase its ranking. Sigh.)

This is why I think that, e.g., [What blogging engine supports markdown?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/need-a-blogging-engine-that-accepts-markdown) is a good question, while "What blogging engine supports RSS?" should be mercilessly answered, "All of them". (And then closed, locked, caged and drowned.)

<sub>I haven't lurked enough to make good examples here. Sorry.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should!