# Why was my question converted to Community Wiki by a mod?

Tags: support

My question was converted to a Community Wiki by a mod, why did they do that?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is because the question is one of the following:

- subjective (e.g. there is no right answer)
- a poll
- [list of... question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic) (e.g. a [webapp-rec](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/what-does-tag-mean-when-is-it-used/480#480) question)

#### Quotes from the Stack Overflow Team

> Well said. The most gratuitous example
>   is probably "favorite programming
>   cartoon". Is it appropriate for
>   someone to get 1,000+ reputation by
>   posting their favorite XKCD? They
>   didn't exactly do anything... – Jeff
>   Atwood♦ [Mar 29 at 3:42](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44388/why-do-some-highly-voted-questions-become-community-wiki#comment-101140)

> To mitigate the large reputation
>   gained from relatively *little*
>   contribution in content, we ask that
>   "list of X" (i.e. poll-style)
>   questions be made community wiki from
>   the outset. – Robert Cartaino♦ [Jul 2 at 23:46](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/is-community-wiki-the-synonym-for-poll/173#173)

> the more a question produces answers
>   that are not original content, the
>   more it should be cwiki. we explicitly
>   discourage answers that are simple
>   links, or trivial cut-pasted content.
>   We want original contributions. Tell
>   us what YOUR experiences were and how
>   YOU solved this problem. – [Jeff Atwood](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/38825?offset=-420)♦

#### Links

- [Why do some highly voted questions become community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44388/why-do-some-highly-voted-questions-become-community-wiki)
- [When to mark the ‘community wiki’ checkbox on a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question)
- [Is “community wiki” the synonym for “poll”?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/is-community-wiki-the-synonym-for-poll)
- [Should moderators be making questions community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24502/should-moderators-be-making-questions-community-wiki)